# search a file using the api of the Autodesk Construction Cloud

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

If I don't know the folder name the only solution I am aware of is  recursively iterate through the folder hierarchy in the project and search for the file in each folder. This method may involve multiple API calls and can take some time, especially if the folder hierarchy is large.
Is there an endpoint in any of the api's which I can use for a search by the attributes of a file?

CK

I tried to find any endpoint in different api's (acc, bim 360, v1, v2)

Answer (score 0):

There is Data Management API search.

https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-folders-folder_id-search-GET/

Maybe this help. There is no search API under ACC/BIM 360 API category.